# R generates fewer random numbers than specified with rnorm, rexp, rpois and runif

Tags: r, floating-point

I have to generate random numbers for two groups of a vector of size N.

The probability for one group is p, and for the other is q = 1-p. 
(Eg. for a population of 1000 with p=0.5, I have to generate 500 random number from a distribution and 500 from another). 
Since this is a simulation in which I have to vary 'p' I wrote my code to generate like this:

```
group1 = rnorm(n = N*p)
group2 = rnorm(n = N*q) # 1st method
group2 = rnorm(n = (N - N*p)) # 2nd method
```

With both of the above methods, R generates one less random numbers than it should in several rows of group2 (about 35% of rows with the first, and about 12% of rows with the second method).

I run into the same bug with rexp, rpois and runif as well.

Below is the snapshot of both the methods for your reference.

```
#### EXAMPLE SCRIPT #####

N = 1000
p1 = seq(0.01, 0.99, 0.001)
q1 = 1 - p1


### FIRST METHOD ###

X = data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(p1))
{
X[i, 1] = p1[i]
X[i, 2] = q1[i]
X[i, 3] = length(runif((N * X[i, 1])))
X[i, 4] = length(runif((N * X[i, 2])))
X[i, 5] = X[i, 4] + X[i, 3]
}

table(X[, 5] == 1000) # column three + coulmn four should sum to 1000


### SECOND METHOD ###

Y = data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(p1))
{
Y[i, 1] = p1[i]
Y[i, 2] = q1[i]
Y[i, 3] = length(runif((N * Y[i, 1])))
Y[i, 4] = length(runif((N - N * Y[i, 1])))
Y[i, 5] = Y[i, 3] + Y[i, 4]
}

table(Y[, 5] == 1000) # column three + coulmn four should sum to 1000
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R FAQ 7.31 - rounding error - your particular problem boils down to this:

```
> p=0.32
> p*1000 + (1-p)*1000
[1]1000
```

well that looks correct. But is it really?

```
> (p*1000 + (1-p)*1000) == 1000
[1] FALSE
```

No. Why not? How wrong is it?

```
> (p*1000 + (1-p)*1000) - 1000
[1] -1.136868e-13
```

1 part in 10^-13. Which means:

```
> length(runif(1000*p))
[1] 320
> length(runif(1000*(1-p)))
[1] 679
```

because:

```
> as.integer(1000*p)
[1] 320
> as.integer(1000*(1-p))
[1] 679
```

which adds up to 999. See the R FAQ 7.31 for details on floating point approximations

The solution is to work in integers as much as possible when dealing with counts.

```
> Np = as.integer(1000*p)
> length(runif(Np))
[1] 320
> length(runif(1000-Np))
[1] 680
```

rather than computing `q` as `1-p` and multiplying that by `N` to try and get `1000-N*p`.

Comment: Thanks, and yes: rounding does the trick. Days ago I had a suspicion that the problem has to do something with that either 'n' is integer or not. I should have sticked to that idea... Anyway, thank you again!