# unexpected behavior of rep() in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a vector in R using the `rep()` function

```
p <- .9
n <- 100
rep(8,n*(1-p)^2) # expect 8
```

What is causing the unexpected behavior?

Comment: @Frank - yep, `as.integer(n*(1-p)^2)` returns `0` - as does `as.integer(0.99999)`

Comment: this is basically FAQ 7.31, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296576/r-generates-fewer-random-numbers-than-specified-with-rnorm-rexp-rpois-and-runi/26297615#26297615

Comment: @Dave `identical(n*(1-p)^2,1)` is false, as is `n*(1-p)^2==1`. R doesn't store such numbers precisely.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is in the comments to the question. A workaround is using:

```
rep(8, round(n*(1-p)^2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Condensing the comments. The second argument of `rep` should be an integer. From the help page: `?as.integer`, we know that real numbers are truncated towards zero. So

```
n*(1-p)^2
```

is passed to

```
as.integer(n*(1-p)^2)
```

which is equal to `0`.